# Run a Method In thread as it is really slow

Tags: c#, winforms, performance

If i have a method that returns a string as follow :

```
 public string ExecuteCommandSync(object command)
        {
            string result = "";
            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
                    new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);


                procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

                procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

                System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
                proc.Start();

                result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            catch (Exception objException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error : " + objException.Message);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Now this works fine for small data but if i have large data it hangs..

If I put this in thread would that make it quicker for large data or at least improve ,as Im completely new to threading and i dont know how to return the result as string again with thread...

can someone help please.

thanks

**EDIT :**

It is a c# winform application running on windows 7.
Basically the idea is to invoke the cmd command and run a command ...
This is the error i get when running from visual studio :

```
The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x8d85c0 to COM context 0x8d8730 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long running operations.
```

**EDIT 2::** 
Ok here is what i have done so far

```
public string ExecuteCommandSync(object command)
        {
            string result = "";
            try
            {

                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(command);
            }
            catch (Exception objException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error : " + objException.Message);
            }

            return result;
        }
  private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            string result;
            Thread.Sleep(300);
            object command = (object)e.Argument;
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
                   new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);


            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            proc.Start();

            result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            results = (string)e.Result;
        }
```

and then i call it using :

```
string result1 = ExecuteCommandSync(command);
```

Comment: You need to give us more context - are you running this within a WinForms app, WPF, something server-side?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Running a code in another thread won't reduce the time needed to run that code. It will only result in a better user experience, because the program doesn't hang.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry it is a winform application in c#

Comment: @AmarPalsapure i have updated the description hope it is clear

Comment: what kind of command you executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your program:

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

And also:

```
void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string result = (string)e.Result;
    //do what you need with it.
}

void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //do your work here
    e.Result = yourResult;
}
```

But also keep in mind what others have said: A thread will not run quicker than a non-threaded program. The benefit will be that the program won't "hang".

Comment: can you check my code on edit2 please it is not working i dont get result back

Comment: @Sam1 `e.Result` instead of `result` in the end of the `DoWork`.

Comment: @Sam1 Additionally, when you call `ExecuteCommandSync` - the result you get will always be `""`. Whatever it is you want to do with the result of the `proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` should be done in the `RunWorkerCompleted` method. (You can call some other method there if you want.) For example: `Text = (string)e.Result;`.

Answer (score 4):

```
            result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

That's the statement that causes your main UI thread to hang.  The ReadToEnd() call won't complete until the process you started stops running.  The "The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context..." message is just a warning, triggered when the debugger also noticed that your main thread went dead.  It is guessing it might be caused by a deadlock.

Threading is indeed your solution, simply move this code into the DoWork event handler for a BackgroundWorker.  Read [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hybbz6ke%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for guidance.

Comment: I created a backgroundworker and assigned result to it but still hangs, here is the code have i done it correctly ?  BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

                bw.RunWorkerAsync(result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

Comment: Right, that doesn't help.  Follow the advice in the answer, the ReadToEnd() call must be made *inside* the DoWork event handler.  Just move all of the code.

Comment: please check edit2 on original post i have done that but dont work

Comment: You don't assign e.Result in DoWork()

Answer (score 0):

You could use an event. When your thead has finished, it throws an event and it give the String to the event.

Comment: but would that make it faster as I am running this for large data and getting cls error

Answer (score 0):

Another thread won't make it run faster, because the time taken to wait for an application to do something isn't affected by which tread is doing it.

However, that isn't your problem, your problem is that *the UI thread* is taking too long. Non-UI threads can merrily take years to do something without triggering that error, so it will indeed solve the problem.

Another approach is to not do `ReadToEnd()` but to read and process smaller chunks as they come. Depending on the nature of the program you are calling into this could solve all your issues (if the program starts responding quickly and the reason you've such a delay is that it's sending a massive amount of data to output) or not (if the program takes a few minutes to send a single byte, then you've the same problem as before.

The two can be combined, with another thread reading chunks at a time from the called program's standard output, and updating state accordingly as it goes.